# Can I add a wildcard dependency to a deb package?

Tags: dependencies, packaging, deb

I am creating a deb package which depends on a long list of packages, all of them starting with `aisoy-`. When installing with apt-get, I can install them all using `apt-get install aisoy-*` but if I write that in the control file for the deb package, It fails with `dpkg-gencontrol: failure: error detected when analyzing «Depends» field`.

My control file is very simple:

```
Source: aisoy-raspberry
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Maintainer: [omitted]
Build-Depends:
Homepage: [omitted]

Package: aisoy-raspberry
Architecture: any
Depends: [other packages that work well], aisoy-*
Description: All packages needed to install Aisoy in Raspberry Pi
```

Is there a way of including all `aisoy-*` packages at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible as you have to be explicit.
If you look at the [Debian packaging library code](https://sources.debian.org/src/dpkg/1.21.21/scripts/Dpkg/Deps/Simple.pm/#L167), the regular expression for a dependency is quite simple.

It only matches against a package name containing: `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9+.-]*`

Comment: Link doesn't work. Can you add solution to the answer, please?